# MultiHop swap buying less than specified `buyAmount` without reverting

Tags: 0x

While using the 0xAPI I noticed that when executing "MultiHop" swaps against my local mainnet fork it sometimes obtains less than the specified `buyAmount` without reverting.

Is this expected behaviour? I assumed that a trade with specified `buyAmount` should revert if it obtains less than that amount, which seems to be true for all other types / liquidity sources.

More Detail:
This seems to be true only when I set `slippagePercentage` > 0. Without `slippagePercentage` the trade reverts with `MultiplexFeature::_multiplexMultiHopSell/UNDERBOUGHT`.

However from the Api documentation I assumed that this slippagePercentage only affects the side of the trade that is not "fixed". (i.e. the `sellAmount` in this case).

For example (at the time of posting this question) with this api query:
`https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0x6B3595068778DD592e39A122f4f5a5cF09C90fE2&sel lToken=0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f&buyAmount=100000000000000000000000&slippagePercentage=0.2`

I got the following "sources" in the api response:

```
[
  {
    proportion: '1',
    intermediateToken: '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2',
    hops: [ 'Uniswap_V3', 'SushiSwap' ],
    name: 'MultiHop'
  }
]
```

But when executing the swap it only obtained `96468.20` instead of the specified `100000` Sushi Tokens.

The code to rerun this Test / Experiment can be found here:
https://github.com/ckoopmann/0xApiExperiments/blob/main/test/index.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now be fixed. Apologies for the delay